# How does the CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH environment variable work for both the mainnet and testnet?

Tags: cardano-cli

According to [the docs](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/running-cardano#querying-the-cardano-blockchain),

> cardano-cli and other Cardano software components need to know where the node socket file is located. We saved it to the path $HOME/cardano/db/node.socket in the previous example. The components read the shell environment variable CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH to find this.

It seems like this node socket file is specific to either the testnet or the mainnet, not both. Are you supposed to change the `CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH` environment variable every time you want to use the CLI tools with a different network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses the same environment variable. I've not needed to change the node socket when I switch between testnet or mainnet.

Comment: Does that mean that `carano-node`'s db directory should be the same for testnet than for mainnet?

Comment: no, the test net is a different chain so it wouldn't use the same db as the mainnet.

Comment: but it's ok for the node socket path to be in the same directory as the mainnet's db?

Comment: yes, a node socket is only telling what port to use to communicate with a given node. So it can be the same port for a mainnet node and testnet node.

Comment: When the node is running and you go to that directory where you have your node socket, you'll find its a text file that is made when you run the node.

Answer (score 0):

The node.socket is a mechanism called IPC (Inter-process communication) that basically helps a CLI instance connect to the active node which is currently syncing the blockchain to your PC (local node instance).

Refer to https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/running-cardano/ and search for "--socket-path:" to jump to the relevant section which tells you more about this.

Assuming that you aren't syncing BOTH the mainnet and testnet **at the same time**, you can provide the same node.socket path to the cardano-node or cardano-cli instance and things should work fine... (Experts, please correct me if this isn't how it works, as I haven't tried syncing both nets at the same time).

In any case, whether you sync to mainnet or testnet, the ledger data itself is downloaded to a particular path using the ----database-path option for cardano-node. As long as you specify different paths for testnet or mainnet, you should be good to go...